# Create numpy array with variable ndim depending on input ndim

Tags: python, numpy

For some reason I'm writing a funtion that creates an array to contain a given array (usually an image) which will have `ndim` property equalling 2 or 3, I can't know in advance. Curently I'm doing something like:

```py
import numpy as np
def create_greater_array(im, scale):

    shape = (im.shape[0] * scale + 2, im.shape[1] * scale + 2)
    if im.ndim==3: #if image is RGB
        shape = *shape, 3
    greater_array = np.fill(shape, np.nan)
    return greater_array
```

What I'm courious is if I can avoid the extra `if` check. In reality my code is actually a class deffinition and does quite a bit more, so I ended up adding an `._is_RBG` attribute to the class.

What I'm thinking is that since the last dimension is always either 3 or nonexistant, it might be automatable.

EDIT: Another case where I need the check in the same program.

I later have another function that inserts images into the array:

```py
def insert_image(im):
    big = create_greater_array(im, 2)
    if im.ndims == 2:
        big[1:im.shape[0]+1, 1:im.shape[1]+1] = im
    else:
        big[1:im.shape[0]+1, 1:im.shape[1]+1, :] = im

    return big
```

Comment: How would that make your code better?  Nothing wrong with a `if` test here and there.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be better, it's just that I'm curious to know if I'm missing somethinig. Also, I'm editing the question to reflect another instance where i need the check. It's just I'm eager to learn, no crucial thing.